# Selecting text with different colors when we tap and hold on text using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, selection, colorbox

I'm developing a web app using HTML5 and Jquery. I'm trying to select the text with different colors by user choice when we tap and hold on text in device. By default when we tap and hold on text it will selecting in light blue color. I want to change that color into different color(user's choice). For selecting colors I'm using

```
<label>Color: <input type="color" class="strokeColor" value="black"></label>
```

When I click on this `<input>` its opening a box with colors from that box I'm selecting one color for selecting the text.

```
 var strokeColorSel, strokeWidthSel;
var strokeColor;        //line color
var strokeWidth = 5;    //line width
var isMoved = false;    //flag for displaying when simple touching
    var context;
//touch events handler
strokeColorSel = document.querySelector(".strokeColor");
context = $(this).text();

        context.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler, false);
        context.addEventListener("touchend", touchEndHandler, false);
        context.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMoveHandler, false);

        //Apply eventHandler
        strokeColorSel.addEventListener("change", changeStrokeColor, false);
```

By using above code I'm selecting the color but the color is not applying on the text when I tap and hold on text.

My text is in this

```
chapterHTML += '<p id="text"><sup>'+ (i+1) +'</sup> '+ vers.text() +'</p>';

$("#text").bind("taphold", touchStartHandler);
```

Any help how to apply the selected color from the box when we tap and hold on text.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attaching  event listeners to a string.

```
context = $(this).text();

context.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler, false);
...
```

Try:

```
context = this;

context.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler, false);
...
```

Assuming this is a DOM node. It's difficult to tell.

Otherwise, please provide a http://jsfiddle.net of your issue. Your code fragments seem incomplete.

Comment: that fiddle contains errors. I fixed the obvious ones, but then there was no text or anything to illustrate the issue you were having.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to attach events to text. You need to wrap the text in a `span` or some other DOM node to attach events to it.

Comment: I tried in another way If i give color dynamically but the text is hightlighting when i taphold on text along with color

Comment: but touchstart,touchmove,touchend is not working device for taphold